# Lighting requires extreme values (Blender 2.8)

Tags: light, lighting

I recently started learning Blender and been following one of Blenderguru's tutorials on lighting ([found here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bum0F00TaKU&list=PLjEaoINr3zgH9vCr47kSS5W8PEJBNIiwK&index=7)) but for some reason my lights, using the exact same scene, requires extreme values to give off any noticeable light. His light is around 50w but for me I need around 500w to achieve a similar effect. I tried applying the scale of everything in the scene but it didn't make a difference. I also checked to see the units were set up correctly (metric/meter) which they were as far as I can tell.

It feels like the range of the light is very short because if I move the light really close it does get much brighter. Maybe there's some falloff setting I need to adjust? .. Happy for any advice on what might be wrong!

[image]

And this is my settings:

[image]

The file I'm using is shared by Blenderguru with a link in the description of the video. Here's the file I used:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lqspxls3yte73f8/Mafia4%20%281%29.blend?dl=0

Also here's how my image looks with False Color activated:
[image]

Compared to BlenderGuru's image:
[image]

Could something like this be impacted by hardware or software related outside of blender? Like a scene should render the exact same end result on two different computers given all settings are equal right?!

Comment: It might be the Filmic-RGB color setting, he uses it very often. Do you have it installed?

Comment: I have it set to: sRGB/Filmic

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing extreme about the values. You should not worry about them. Those are only numbers. It doesn't matter if it's 1 or 1000000. The proportions matter more - if you have sunlight in the scene it should not be dimmer than light from a light bulb and so on.

If it is more convenient for you to work with some specific units you can adjust the exposure to match them in the Color Management settings:

[image]

or under Film settings:

[image]